# What is the largest $a$ for which all the solutions to the equation $3x^2+ax-(a^2-1)=0$ are positive and real?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem:** What is the largest $a$ for which all the solutions to the equation $3x^2+ax-(a^2-1)=0$ are positive and real?

**Attempt:** Solving the equation for $x$ I get $$x_{1,2}=-\frac{a}{6}\pm\sqrt{\frac{13a^2-12}{36}}.$$

For the roots to be real, the discriminant as to be greater than or equal to zero, so it yields the inequality

$$13a^2-12 \geq 0\Leftrightarrow -\frac{2\sqrt{39}}{13}\leq a\leq\frac{2\sqrt{39}}{13}.$$

Condition number two is that both roots should be positive. How should I think to proceed?

Comment: if the two roots are positive, $-b/2a$ is positive and $f(0)$ is also positive.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: @Paul Oh sorry clearly missed that!

Comment: @samjoe My mistake actually. I thought the quadratic was positive definite. To OP; try finding the product of roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the inequality you end up with is wrong: you need either
$$a \leq -\frac{2\sqrt{39}}{13} \;\;\;\text{     or     }\;\;\; a \geq \frac{2\sqrt{39}}{13}$$

Since the root 
$$x_2 = -\frac{a}{6} - \sqrt{\frac{13a^2 - 12}{36}} = \frac{1}{6}\left(-a - \sqrt{13a^2 - 12}\right)$$
is always smaller than $x_1$ (when both are real, of course), it suffices to find the largest $a$ such that $x_2$ is positive.

Hence we are looking for the largest $a$ such that
$$-a - \sqrt{13a^2 - 12} \geq 0.$$

Now, as the root is always positive and minus the root is therefore negative, obviously we'll need $a \leq 0$. Rearrange as
$$-a \geq \sqrt{13a^2 - 12}$$
and square both sides to find
$$a^2  \geq 13a^2 - 12,$$
and rearrange again to find 
$$12 \geq 12a^2$$
or hence
$$1\geq a^2.$$
Since $a$ must be negative, this means that $-1 \leq a \leq 0$.

Therefore, the values of $a$ such that the equation has $2$ (not necessarily distinct) real roots which are both positive, are
$$a \in \left[-1,-\frac{2\sqrt{39}}{13}\right]$$
hence the largest such $a$ is $-\frac{2\sqrt{39}}{13}$

Comment: I like this solution! +1

Comment: 1) "Now, as the root is always positive and minus the root is therefore negative, obviously we'll need..." Why?


2) "Since $a$ must be negative, this means that..." Why?


3) How did you, with only a pen and a paper, find out that $$-1<\frac{2\sqrt{39}}{13} \ ?$$

Comment: 1) A square root is defined to be positive. So we have $$-a - (\text{ something positive} ) \geq 0,$$ or thus 
$$- a + (\text{ something negative }) \geq 0.$$
If $a$ were also positive, then $-a$ would also be negative, and the sum of two negative things is negative. So the entire left-hand side would be negative.

Comment: 2) if $1 \geq a^2$, then by taking the root of both sides, $1 \geq |a|$, or thus $-1 \leq a \leq 1$. But since $a$ is negative, we reduce this to $-1 \leq a \leq 0$.

Comment: 3) I simply followed your "style" of only having roots in the numerator. We were originally dealing with the inequality $13a^2 - 12 \geq 0$, or thus $a^2 \geq \frac{12}{13}$, and therefore $a \geq \sqrt{\frac{12}{13}} = \frac{2\sqrt{39}}{13}$ or $a \leq -\sqrt{\frac{12}{13}} = -\frac{2\sqrt{39}}{13}$. It's easy to see that $\sqrt{12/13} < 1$.

Answer (score 3):

The conditions:

a) $\Delta \ge 0$ (the discriminant)

b)  The sum of the roots is positive (Use Vieta)

c) The product of the roots is positive (Use Vieta)

Comment: What does the first triangle mean?

Comment: @Parseval see the updated answer

Comment: How did I miss this? :(

Comment: So, the inequalitites I for b) and c) get should be 

b ) $$-a > 0 \Leftrightarrow a < 0$$

c) $$-(a^2-1) > 0 \Leftrightarrow  a > 1 \ \text{or} \ a<-1$$

Comment: @Parseval Yes ....

Answer (score 2):

The equation is : $3x^2+ax-(a^2-1)=0$

- First condition is which you identified, that the **discriminant** must be positive.
- Note that  the abscissa of **vertex** of this parabola is $\dfrac{-b}{2a}$ . For both roots to be positive, this value must be positive
- Furthermore, since the parabola is upward, $f(0) > 0$ implies that both roots must be positive.

These are the three conditions which yield the sought answer.